# How to update workspace variable content for every iteration in matlab?

Tags: matlab

So I have this code

```
h = SomeFunction;
h.run
for k = 1:4
    data_local = h.data;
    data_local = data_local+rand(1)
    plot(data_local);
    pause(2);
end
```

which outputs 128x25 matrix every second(with a time gap of 2 secounds)

so for each iteration I want this to update the variable in the work space so i used

```
assignin('base','data',data_local)
```

inside the loop.

this seems to work, but the thing is only the last value is being stored (after the loop is completed).

Can anyone tell me how to update the variable in the workspace on each loop?

thanks in advance.

**Update**

this is where the actual file is [EmotivEEG headset toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36111-emotiveeg-headset-toolbox)

Comment: 1. Use the index `i ` to place the variable in position `i` (Check out evalin, and you might consider using cells or a 3D-matrix if the output of each loop is a 2D-matrix). 2. It's bad practice to use `i` as a variable name, as it also represents the imaginary unit in MATLAB.

Comment: @StewieGriffin It seems there may be a reason that OP wants to update the workspace more frequent. The values may be streamed here or there may be a memory issue so that he wants to 1) temporary store the value 2) do something with it 3) discard it. Storing 25 kB per  is not much but it may add up in a couple of days. However, the post is not clear on that point so your comment, so I think that the comment is valuable. Anyway, the overhead for using `i` as iteration variable is small and it is bad practice to use `i` or `j` as imaginary numbers, so this should not be a problem.

Comment: akshay, it would help if you could explain a bit the motivation for your question. Is this code contained into a function, so the point is to export from the function's workspace into the global workspace? If not, and you run this directly on the command line or a script, there's nothing special to do, you have direct access to the global workspace. Or is the problem that you want to keep all 4 different values? Then using indexing is the way to go, as StewieGriffin wrote. Don't worry about `i` as an iteration variable though, there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @A.Donda `somefunction` is an .m (class i guess) file, and h.run is a function in that .m file. this code is as a script. this is where i got the actual file from [Emotiv EEG Tool box](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36111-emotiveeg-headset-toolbox)

Comment: @patrik so the thing is i want to first process this data then when the processing is completed i want to discard it.

Comment: @akshay So with "this data" you mean every chunk (so to say one data element, which is the same you want to pass to base)? Or do you want to collect all data and process everything at the same time? In case of the first option, could you specify what you want to do with it when you pass it to base? The best option may rely on how heavy work to do.

Comment: @patrik so this thing is a matrix of 128x25 (you can call each iteration as one chunk of data), so at every iteration i want to process this data, once the process is done i want to get rid of it.

Comment: @akshay Ok, so then I know what you want to do. So are you running single thread? Are you using parallel processing toolbox? What is the reason to assign the variable in base? I case you are not using parallel processing toolbox, do you have a plan to how to run the code in base during the time? And more importantly, if you are running single thread, does the processing take more than 2 seconds? The reason that I ask is that your question is more about design than finding some kind of function.

Comment: @akshay Ok, I think that I know what you wanted to do after looking at the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058891/while-loop-in-matlab-to-increment-a-number) you submitted. This information should have been here, since without that it is like saying, can you help me to design motor to a car, it must be made of metal (what car?). But anyway, what I would go for another design. I would have the main loop in main and then start the processing there. Then I would check if the function returns a value and if that update the matrix. Else only update the screen.

Comment: Sorry if I extend the comment this far. But this will not force you to pass variables to base, which anyway makes the code less thread safe (if you try to access the variable from base and change it from another scope at the same time, with a runtime evaluated function). Also, you do not need to run the callback all the time. And when the processing is done, you can let the program rest to time that is left and so save processor power (and battery for a laptop!).